# Spring Boot on Elastic Beanstalk worker tier

Tags: spring, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a spring boot app into one EB worker tier but seems that EB it is not ready to manage this kind of project.

Have I to mandatory generate a .war from my spring boot app?

Thanks!

Comment: Java Tomcat applications are supported with EB worker tier. Can you try using your app with "64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.7 running Tomcat 7 Java 7"

Comment: I have just added the solution :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the problem.

EB expects a .war file and Spring Boot app usually is launche by a embedded Tomcat or Jetty.

I have found the solution in this guide:

http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Summing up:

1. Add tomcat dependency with provided scope in pom.xml

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Create a class extending SpringBootServletInitializer and load the entrypoint within this class. This way, we are indicating to the servlet container how to launch the app.

   ```
   package com.proyecti.magma.conversionsworker.config.servlet;

   import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
   import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

   import com.proyecti.magma.conversionsworker.entrypoint.Application;

   public class ServletConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer
   {
       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
           return application.sources(Application.class);
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: Hi did you try using Spring Boot + tomcat on ElasticBeanstalk with SSL?

Comment: Hi, sorry but I have not been dealing with SSL yet. Can this help you? http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-configure-ssl

Comment: Could please share your instance configuration? Which Tomcat, which Java etc. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but I am not working on that project now. I remember by heart that it was the default image provided using AWS wizard and customziations were related to install some required libraries using an initialization script inside a .ebextensions folder as well as enable websockets (this post can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460832/websocket-with-tomcat-7-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk). Hope it helps!