# ELB for Websockets SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Does AWS support websockets with SSL ?

Can EWS ELB be used for websockets over SSL ?

What happens when a EC2 instance(machine) is added or removed to this ELB. Especially removed; what if a machine goes down. are the existing sockets routed to some other machine or reseted to connected.

can ELB be a bottleneck at any point in time.

any other alternatives .. let me know

Answer (score 0):

This link might prove partially helpful for you - it would appear that you can do web sockets over SSL, but currently I'm struggling to implement it.

[StackOverflow - Websocket with Tomcat 7 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460832/websocket-with-tomcat-7-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 0):

Currently AWS ELB doesn't support Websocket balancing, there is a trick to do it via SSL, but it has some limitation and depends on your app logic. So if websocket connection is used only as server-client communication, it will work. But if you have more advanced logic when clients must communicate with each other via  a server then this solution won't work. For example one client has established connection for a chatroom, then other clients can connect to the established chatroom and communicate with each other.

Then only possible way to use HA-proxy http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/11/07/websockets-load-balancing-with-haproxy/

But shown example just shows how to configure HA-proxy base on two servers. So if you do not use Amazon Autoscalling Group, the solution is good. But if you will need use ASG, the question about add/remove instances to ha-proxy config is other challenge.