# How to Enable WebSocket request in AWS Elastic Beanstalk deployed Java web application

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

First of all, I'm new to `socket` programming and `AWS beanstalk`.
AS per my initial investigation I have founded `AWS Elastic Beanstalk(EB)` not support `WebSocket`. So I need to do a workaround on `EB` to enable that.
I have developed a java application with one `WebSocket` request for notification. Its working fine in local machines when I deployed to `AWS EB` the `WebSocket` request-response  **501** status code. I just investigate this issue I found we need to work around for enabling `WebSocket` request in `EB`. but I have no more idea how it does. I'm stuck in This situation. I Already have Load Balancer And security certificate.that are enabled on my `EB`.
How can I enable `WebSocket` request without fail existing conditions?

I found One solution But I have doubt Where it put the configuration file described in this link [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460832/websocket-with-tomcat-7-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the java application you are running, but I know about how to setup your Elastic Load Balancer to work with websockets.

First of all, websockets doesn't work through CloudFront so you need to setup a separate domain (i.e. websockets.domain.com) that points directly to your load balancer, an A record alias.

Second, setup a new listener to your Elastic Load Balancer to use TCP and SSL. Generate a certificate through ACM.

[image]

Last, change your websocket client to use your new domain and port.

Comment: Ok . i have one doubt whein call to he websoket how cai define the wesoket uri. Is it use new subdomain as prefix?

Comment: You need to set it up in Route 53 or wherever you host your domain. Then you need to call this domain with your websocket client. Make sure you use he correct port as well.